# What happens if I undelete an answer to a migrated question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, closed-questions

When a question is migrated, all its answers get migrated with it (presumably). One thing I've noticed is the option to `undelete` my answer on the `?noredirect=1` landing page for the question (i.e. as it was before migration).

Why does it say that my answer is deleted as opposed to migrated? What happens if I undelete it? The [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#deletion) does not explain answers being deleted due to migration.

For example: https://superuser.com/questions/396949/how-to-group-all-emails-from-one-user-into-one-collection-in-gmail?noredirect=1

[image: migrated]

[image: undelete]

---

> ### Ok! I'm going to click it...
>
> [image: vote]

## This is it! I can do this!

[image: ok]

#### O... K...

## ...

> [image: undeleted]
>
> It actually worked.
>
> ## What?

---

I've also noticed that when a question is undeleted, any reputation previously earned is restored. So, theoretically, I can clone the answer's reputation every time it get's migrated and undeleted. So, uh, how many times can a question be migrated?

Comment: I went through my vote limit by the two `/review` pages *in the first minutes* of this day, can't try it... :(

Comment: At least the question is locked.

Comment: Migration seems to reset everything, including edits, do this makes sense as being possible from a migration standpoint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intended? You can undelete migrated answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41160/intended-you-can-undelete-migrated-answers)

Comment: @CodyGray, Link down....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no longer possible to undelete an answer to a question that was migrated away. While we have a job that takes care of this, being able to do it in the first place causes unneeded fluctuations to other things...so now we prevent it at the time of the undelete vote.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, being able to undelete the deleted post-migration posts doesn't really matter - migration stubs are deleted [after 30days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79082/133693) and any orphan posts that are left behind are deleted by another [daily background process](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2680/4377).

At the end of the day, you are left with a deleted answer, no matter even if you chose to undelete it.