# Has reputation for deleted posts been removed again?

Tags: discussion, support

There was a decision to give reputation for helpfull deleted posts.

Not everyone agreed with this: [Deleted posts should not influence reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/deleted-posts-should-not-influence-reputation)

Has this decision been reversed?

My rep on SO droped from 23775 to 23522 points overnight with no explaination, I am wondering if that is the reason.

Comment: Not *all* deleted questions count towards your reputation. Details are contained in [the blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/); see point number one.

Comment: there is not any one spesific post, I gained ca. 400 points when they made the change, now I have lost them again

Comment: +1 I have an unexplained adjustment too. I happened to take a screenshot of something at 18:00 yesterday and that shows my rep was 86,055 then. Since then my rep tab shows +40 gains but my actual rep is 85,910 not 86,095 giving an unaccounted for 185 discrepancy.

Comment: Maybe something to do with [this bug fix for migrated questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125102/145673). I've had plenty of migrated answers so may well be affected. TBH despite reading Nick's answer a couple of times I'm still not really sure what the bug that was fixed was though.

Comment: @Mark it feels like the fix zapped all my deleted question votes, not just those that were migrated.

Comment: I refreshed my StackOverflow window this morning and saw the rep score going down by 10, even though the reputation tab says I gained 165 overnight. Something's definitely not right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bug that we fixed recently that [allowed rep to be kept for migrated answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125102/145673).

When a post is migrated, rep on the source site should not be kept because the rep is transferred to the destination site.

Your reputation was temporarily falsely increased by this bug, and has now been brought back to where it should be.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to the 500 rep I lost over this "adjustment", I got to experience the thrill of crossing 200K all over again (see comments of [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/894385/6309))

Comment: Thanks Rebecca - in such case of rep loss, will it be visible in the reputation history?

Comment: My rep just jumped to 23847, looks like I go it back again :)