# Privilege lost at migration

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

I'm quite new to Stack Overflow. But a thing that I see as a bug that you can lose reputation when a question is migrated to [Super User](http://superuser.com). That happened to me so I also lost my privilege to vote up.

In my opinion the privileges that you earn/gain must be static, also the reputation². Why would you lose it when its migrated to Super User.

² I mean when its migrating, of course bounties and such its obvious its removed.

Maybe its a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/is-losing-privileges-after-placing-bounty-ok) not sure, that's why I post.

Comment: The reputation is different for every site; therefore, your privileges may be different. Why should they be equal across all sites? The StackExchange system hosts a broad range of topics. How would someones experience with software development have to do with their knowledge of photography or home improvement.

Comment: There was [actually was a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124953/does-it-make-sense-that-migrated-questions-doubles-your-network-reputation) where you *did* keep the rep so this definitively isn't a bug. You could make a feature-request but I don't think that's going to happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The votes on the posts are moved along with the post and reputation is separate on all sites (after all, just because you're good at programming doesn't mean you're an expert, say, photographer).

So in some cases, yes, you can drop below a privilege threshold on the source site. Consequently, you can gain privileges on the other site after a migration, though you're not quite there yet with just one upvote on your answer. Hopefully more to come!

Comment: I found it quite hard to help people as there are so much questions asked every time I refresh. (To find topics where I have knowledge of) But I mean if you earn a privilege it shouldn't get removed because the questions was moved to another site. I think privilege you earn shouldn't be removed except if you abuse them in some way.

Comment: @iVision If the question was migrated, that means it was deemed off-topic for the source site. The rep. deduction is justified. The loss of privileges is a consequence of losing rep., that's all.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Oh I misunderstood migration then, and the whole 'Super User' thank you for all replies!

Answer (score 1):

The reputation is different for every site; therefore, your privileges may be different. Why should they be equal across all sites? The StackExchange system hosts a broad range of topics.
This can easily be seen by viewing all of the stackechange sites at the bottom of the page.

How would someones experience with software development be a good representation of their knowledge of photography or home improvement?

Since your question was migrated, it was deemed off topic for stackoverflow; therefore, the rep you gained would be unmerited. You did not completely lose your rep; it was just transferred to SuperUser along with your question. Do not fret; you will regain the upvote privilege soon enough.

Comment: The OP seems upset that they lost upvote privileges on SO because a question was migrated, causing their rep to drop below the 15 point threshold.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ If the question was off topic for Stackoverflow and moved to Super User, why would he receive rep for it? He should have asked the question on the right site ;)