# Question does not belong to SO but has been answered on SO, what to do with the answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic, ethics, obsolete-information

One of the first (naive) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357182/vpn-error-800-attempted-vpn-tunnels-failed-windows-7-ikev2) I posted on SO actually belongs to [Super User](https://superuser.com/):

I wanted to ship the question over there despite it being already answered on SO; it received more upvotes than downvotes despite being closed so perhaps there was some community value to it (?).

However, there's a moral dilemma: what do I do with @user3079671's answer? If I answered my own question on Super User I get reputation points that I do not deserve...

Do I leave my question un-answered as a matter of principle?

Comment: Hmm... quick thought: invite user3079671 to make an account on SU and answer there?

Comment: Would I be wrong in saying that if the question is migrated the answer will go with it

Comment: Good idea, will post a comment on the original SO post on his answer, cheers @Louis

Comment: Have you reposted the same question on multiple sites? Thats not really supposed to happen. Flag for migration rather than cross posting

Comment: @RichardTingle no, you wouldn't be wrong... but there's an 'if' there - that I think the question is too old to migrate.

Comment: Oh right... I did not know there was an official way to migrate a question, I thought it'd just involve me copy-pasting it!

Comment: @hello_there_andy one can flag it for migration by a moderator.  There is also the option for some predefined sites to be migrated as part of the off topic close vote path.  Migrating it moves the entire question to the other site including answers and comments.

Comment: @RichardTingle I'd expect the answer to be migrated but it is not clear to me that we're talking about an actual *migration* here. As I recall (perhaps erroneously), mods have said that migrations are rare because there's a whole bunch of conditions that must happen so users might want to move their questions rather than wait for a migration. (This does not mean that anything goes. And indeed asking a mod to delete the original question may be the proper thing to do.) Here, the age of the question sounds like a bar to migration.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelT ... geez I've made a right mess here, I've already posted the question on Super User and made a link to it for the original answerer to go and answer it again...

Comment: The question is too old to be migrated anyway (the window is 90 days).

Comment: @RobertHarvey has that been expanded I always thought it was [60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)?

Comment: @bluefeet: That's what I get for trying to quote these things from memory.

Comment: You guys can't just wave your magical diamonds around and migrate anything?

Comment: @codeMagic: Not after 60 days.

Comment: @codeMagic you are funny our diamonds aren't magical

Comment: They're magical in the same way that mops, trash cans and pressure washers are magical.

Comment: @bluefeet maybe if you had more unicoins you could buy a magical diamond *dang a few days too late on that one*

Comment: @all of you... I thought after reading all of that I'd get at least one step closer to solving this darn moral dilemma. And screw ur magical diamonds dammit why couldn't you just invest in more storage for these migrate-worthy posts.

Comment: For anybody who want's to know why the diamonds aren't magical: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124953/does-it-make-sense-that-migrated-questions-doubles-your-network-reputation

Comment: @hello_there_andy after about two months, most people don't care too much about their questions that they've asked.  I'd say "let this one go, and know better in the future"