# Reset the vote count on reopened questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-reopen

Can we reset vote counts on reopened questions (both positive and negative)?

For questions that are too broad or unclear, the downvote is an appropriate tool in addition to the close system. Downvotes are clear signals that the question doesn't quite fit in.

However, there is a stigma with questions having negative vote counts. I know my eyes glaze over questions having negative vote counts. Should the OP change the question so that it is appropriate and the question is reopened, the negative stigma remains regardless of the validity of the OPs updated question.

I think a user should still receive the negative karma, but the question itself should start with a clean slate much as [migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions) do.

Comment: So what prevents 5 users (or a single user with a dupe-hammer) from resetting the votes on a question with thousands of votes? Case in point: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642028/revisions

Comment: What prevents 5 users with close privilege from closing any valid question?

Comment: I don't think resetting on migration is for the same reason; see [Does it make sense that migrated questions doubles your “Network Reputation”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124953/does-it-make-sense-that-migrated-questions-doubles-your-network-reputation)

Comment: @AndyJones Nothing. But it can be reopened with no net effect. If you're gonna suggest something as drastic as resetting votes, you better have a viable solution of undoing it.

Comment: @AndyJones Your argument in your comment is another reason why your proposal should *not* happen... close a valid question, knowing it'll be reopened, to clear out the votes.

Comment: Does anyone believe that an edited and reopened question that is perfectly valid really gets fair attention with -5 vote count? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But I am sure that with this idea, closing/reopening would be exploited.

Answer (score 6):

Reopening a bad question does not always mean it got better. So bad question which got downvotes should still keep them.

The other way around is also true: good question that was closed and reopened didn't get bad all of a sudden and does not deserve to have its upvotes reset.